# I am getting an error when saving and viewing images to the folder within the Application in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

When I add an icon to the images folder in my application and then add it to the server I want to display; exe closes by pressing the following error. Why could it be?
I can view the file image when I set it as static, but when I want to call it from the application; is closing.
Error Details:
Uygulama: WpfApplication.exe
Framework Sürümü: v4.0.30319
Açıklama: İşlenmeyen bir özel durum nedeniyle işlem sonlandırıldı.
Özel Durum Bilgisi: System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException
konum: System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32, System.String)
konum: System.IO.FileSystemEnumerableIterator`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].CommonInit() konum: System.IO.FileSystemEnumerableIterator`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]..ctor(System.String, System.String, System.String, System.IO.SearchOption, System.IO.SearchResultHandler`1<System.__Canon>, Boolean)
konum: System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(System.String, System.String)
konum: WpfApplication.Wins.Sub_Wins_Pen_IconsShow.GetIconImage()

```
private ImageSource GetIconImage()
        {
           SvgImageSourceExtension svgToImageSource = new SvgImageSourceExtension();
            var uri = "pack://application:,,,//../Images/add.svg";
            svgToImageSource.Uri = new Uri(uri);
            ImageSource image = (ImageSource)svgToImageSource.ProvideValue(null);
            return image;
        }

 private void btnAddSvg_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                var openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog
                {
                    Filter = "SVG Files (*.svg)|*.svg"
                };
                if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
                {
                    var imagePath = openFileDialog.FileName;
                    var uri = string.Format(@"pack://application:,,,//../Images/{0}.svg",Path.GetFileName(openFileDialog.FileName));
                    if (!File.Exists(uri))
                    {
                        File.Copy(imagePath, uri, true);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }
```

I ran it by assigning a default path to the path and I couldn't find any other solution except it worked.

Comment: You can not copy a file to a [Resource File Pack URI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/app-development/pack-uris-in-wpf). This means you can not use Pack URIs to load images that are dynamically added to your application. These files should be stored in a regular file system folder, and of course one in which the application has write permissions. For example in the folder retrieved by [Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.specialfolder).